# Poor performance issue on server versus local performance of an application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, latency

I'm looking for a solution to a performance problem. We are using the following:

- ASP.net
- SQL Server
- Entity framework

I am hoping that someone has run into this issue before and has solved it!

It's taking 2 at 3 times longer to execute an HTTP request on a hosted application compared to running the same application locally on debug. However, if we trace between preinit and rederer, on the server host,we are getting something like 0.250 seconds  request time but, when are watching it, it is actually taking 3 or 4 seconds to render that complete page.

This is driving us crazy! Any ideas as to what is causing this and how to fix it?

Is there a program can we use to check and debug this for it's root cause? If it was happening to you, are there recommendations as to what you would you try?

Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably any of this:

- is the data from the development computer the same that in the production(hosted) server? if not the problem is that you are not using well your ORM or have to optimize your app.
- you can use firebug [net panel](http://getfirebug.com/net.html) to check if the problem is from the network...
- if you are using a VPS and a cheap one, your computer might be better than the server and as the server is shared among several virtual sites their load might affect the performance of your app.

hope it helps.